# Coming back on Play Store after Account Termination (100% Secure)

Tags: android, account, termination

**Background:**
My Play Store account was terminated because it had more then 3 apps suspended on it but it was in the start of my play store account. I was using account for over month after that and no other game got suspended because as i improved the game quality overall. One day they terminated my account that had around 40 games on store live.

**My Research:**
Now i want to get back on Play Store and i know that i need to come up with the following requirements:

- New Machine (To Sign APK packages) (On which old account was never signed in)
- New Internet Connection (not confirmed)
- Buying Developer Account being different Identity (Different Person Credit card on different bank)

**What I Have:**

- A new Machine to Sign APK (Old account was never signed in from this) but it was being used with the same internet.
- A Data SIM to have a new internet with different IP.
- New Person Credit Card from Different Country.

**What I'm Doing Now:**
I have bought the playstore account using a credit card of different country (it is approved and working). I'm uploading games on it and they are live. It has more then 15 games i think. I'm currently Signing APK packages using my University Lab computers and also even publishing the games from there.

**My PROBLEM:**
I cannot upload and Sign all the games from Lab PCs every time. I need a solution to work on it from home. I have two separate laptops at home on which old account was never signed in. But I'm afraid of getting ban again because those two laptops also used the same internet. I gathered information on the dynamic IP from my ISP and they said the IP might switches in several different IP's and it would come to its original IP again at some point. I can use the Data SIM for uploading games but only during the upload time period. Other time those laptops uses the home internet.

**Only Solution in my thinking:**
To buy a new cheap laptop fast enough to sing the APK file for me and a Data SIM to upload and publish those games. It will be only connect to the Data SIM (means no coming back to home internet) and only use to Sign and publish APK's.

**Other Forums Suggestions:**
Format your computer completely and start over using the same internet again but with with different credit card.
I cannot risk it. I need a genuine solution. If the IP is not the issue then i can use the other two spare laptops at my home and my problem would be no longer .

Kindly help me out and give me a right solution and correct me if i'm wrong about any thing.

I'm from Pakistan and [PTCL](https://ptcl.com.pk/) is my network provider. I can use the Data Sim of these [Companies](https://www.google.com.pk/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enPK762PK762&q=mobile%20network%20operators%20in%20pakistan&oq=mobile%20network%20operatirs%20in%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i13k1l4.7011.15066.0.16001.34.24.2.0.0.0.416.3649.3-8j2.10.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..22.12.3654...0j0i67k1j0i22i30k1j0i13i5i30k1.0.dbRLKYwONv4)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Comment: Maybe you could try using a VPN or a browser like Tor so you can use an IP address that is new to google.  Also maybe you can use a VM of some sort (VMPlayer or Oracle Box) for signing your APK's.  I got kicked off of google for making apps that made fun of Hillary Clinton. I publish my apps on Amazon now.  I don't get a nearly the same amount of downloads, but heck what's indie dev to do.

Comment: @dev Have you changed the package name of your apps or is it the same?

Comment: can we use Oracle Virtual Box (Virtual Machine) instead of new machine?

Comment: what does signing an app have to do with the physical computer?

Comment: May i know if the card you used to open another account was also in your name or was it in somebody else's name?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a vps or some server in another country and setup/write a vpn or other proxy-ing agent on it;

Use a virtual machine to connect to the google play developer console and reroute its traffic to the proxy-ing agent;